# How to choose execute from 2 queries depending of the result of a previous query in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have 3 queries in SQLite:

```
-query1: SELECT COUNT(id_asiento) FROM ASIENTOS_DIARIO WHERE id_paquete = 1
-query2: SELECT id_asiento FROM ASIENTOS_DIARIO
-query3: SELECT id_cta FROM CUENTASXPAQ
```

I want to construct a query where I can execute query2 or query3 depending of the number of rows resulting from query1

this is my code:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(id_asiento) FROM ASIENTOS_DIARIO WHERE id_paquete = 1) > 0 
THEN (SELECT id_asiento FROM ASIENTOS_DIARIO)
ELSE (SELECT id_cta FROM CUENTASXPAQ)
END QUERY
```

but when I execute this, only returns the first row of query2 or query3 and I want to get all the rows

how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id_asiento AS ID
FROM ASIENTOS_DIARIO
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(id_asiento) FROM ASIENTOS_DIARIO WHERE id_paquete = 1) > 0 
UNION ALL
SELECT id_cta AS ID
FROM CUENTASXPAQ
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(id_asiento) FROM ASIENTOS_DIARIO WHERE id_paquete = 1) = 0
```

Comment: It worked, gonna update your final query since you're repeating the same query on both situations, thanks for your support!!!

Comment: Your change was wrong. There two conditions should be complementary for each other, must be came from same table. otherwise you may get results from query2 and query3 both.

Comment: you're totally right, the way you left the answer is correct, my bad, thanks dude